# Batch script insert text between 1st and 2nd lines for multiple files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to write a batch script that inserts text between the 1st and 2nd lines for multiple files. The script takes in a text file as an input that includes the path to multiple files. Each file is on its own line as such.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

For each file I read in I at attempting to insert text between the first and second lines.

This is what I have.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

Rem "loop through file names from input file"
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (%1) do (

set source_file="%%a"

Rem Creates text file titled new.txt. 
copy NUL new.txt

set /a count = 0

Rem Loop intended to copy 1st line from source file to new, inserts new text on second line of new
Rem then copies the rest of the source file to new
for /F "tokens=1" %%a in (!source_file!) do (

   IF !count! == 0 (
       Rem copy first line of source code
       ECHO %%a >> new.txt
   )

   IF !count! == 1 (
       Rem insert my text here after 1st line
       ECHO text goes here >> new.txt
       
       Rem still need to copy line from file
       ECHO %%a >> new.txt
  )

  IF !count! gtr 1 (
      Rem copy line from source file. 
      ECHO %%a >> new.txt
  )
set /a count += 1
)

Rem Overwrite source file with new file
type new.txt > !source_file!

Rem delete disclaimer.txt
del new.txt

)
```

My overwritten files contain the name of the file rather than the original contents with new text inserted between lines 1 and 2.

Comment: `for /f %%a in ("string") do ...` : `%%a`  will be the literal `string`. To process a file: `for /f %%a in (file.txt) do ...` or (to disable the "quotes means string"  default): `for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("file.txt") do ...`

Comment: `tokens=1` will do a bad job, when a filename contains a space. Better use `"tokens=*"` or `"delims="`

Comment: Thank you Stephan. Removing the quotes solved my problem.

Comment: Please note that your code would only insert between the first non empty line and the second non empty line. Empty lines in your original source will be completely omitted, and will not appear anywhere in the resulting file.